# Cannot download file from Dropbox

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I am uploading and downloading a file from Dropbox. When I upload a file it uploads it correctly. When I download a file and open it, the file is zero bytes. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Download code:

```
try {
    File localFile = new File(localFilePath);
    File fileSelected = new File(dropboxPath);

    if (!localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.createNewFile();
    } else {
        //copy(fileSelected, localFile);
        //mApi.copy("/Test/test.png", "/sdcard/testfile.png");

        BufferedInputStream br = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bw = null;
        DropboxInputStream fd;
        try {
            fd = mApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.getPath(), null);
            br = new BufferedInputStream(fd);
            bw = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;
            while (true) {
                read = br.read(buffer);
                if (read <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                bw.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }    
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                    if (br != null) {
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }/*
    else {
        showToast("File already exists");
    }*/
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    showToast("Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    showToast("Exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are not calling `close()`

Comment: what is this link for? @fge

Comment: where's the rest of the code? You have a `try` block but don't show the catch/finally - it's going to be difficult to debug with missing information.

Comment: Where are you in debugging this? Do you get any output or errors? At what point does the code stop doing what you expect? E.g., if you print out fileSelected.getPath(), is it the right path for the file in Dropbox that you want? If you print out `read`, does it contain the data you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2010-11 Dropbox, Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */


package codelynks.easydropbox;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry;
import com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxIOException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxParseException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxPartialFileException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxServerException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Here we show getting metadata for a directory and downloading a file in a
 * background thread, trying to show typical exception handling and flow of
 * control for an app that downloads a file from Dropbox.
 */

public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {


    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;

    private Drawable mDrawable;

    private FileOutputStream mFos;

    private boolean mCanceled;
    private Long mFileLen;
    private String mErrorMsg;
    private String mDownloadpath;

    // Note that, since we use a single file name here for simplicity, you
    // won't be able to use this code for two simultaneous downloads.
    private final static String IMAGE_FILE_NAME = "dbroulette.png";

    public Download(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api,
                    String dropboxPath, String downloadpath) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mDownloadpath = downloadpath;
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Downloading File");
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);

        mDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mCanceled = true;
                mErrorMsg = "Canceled";

                // This will cancel the getThumbnail operation by closing
                // its stream
                if (mFos != null) {
                    try {
                        mFos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (mCanceled) {
                return false;
            }

            // Get the metadata for a directory
            Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);

            if (dirent.isDir) {
                // It's not a directory, or there's nothing in it
                mErrorMsg = "Directory Can't be download";
                return false;
            }


            if (mCanceled) {
                return false;
            }

            try {
                mFos = new FileOutputStream(mDownloadpath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                mErrorMsg = "Couldn't create a local file to store the image";
                return false;
            }
            mApi.getFile(mPath, null, mFos, new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long arg0, long arg1) {
                    mFileLen = arg1;//Total File Length
                    publishProgress(arg0);//Downloaded File Length
                }
            });


            if (mCanceled) {
                return false;
            }


            // We must have a legitimate picture
            return true;

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // The AuthSession wasn't properly authenticated or user unlinked.
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Download canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._304_NOT_MODIFIED) {
                // won't happen since we don't pass in revision with metadata
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE) {
                // too many entries to return
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA) {
                // can't be thumbnailed
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int) (100.0 * (double) progress[0] / mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Downloading Finished");
            // Set the image now that we have it
            //mView.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
        } else {
            // Couldn't download it, so show an error
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }


}
```

> Call the background thread like followed

```
Download download = new Download(context, mApi, drop_box_file_path, sdcard_path_to_store);
        download.execute();
```

> Where, mApi is the reference of DropboxAPI