# How can I save a file in android to my Dropbox directory?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dropbox

Currently I'm able to save it to my external SD card, but I'd like to save it to my Dropbox directory.

```
try {
    File root = new File("Dropbox/");
    File gpxfile = new File(root, "test.txt");
    if(!gpxfile.exists()){
         gpxfile.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile, true);
```

and etc.
I do not know if there is anyway to have Dropbox as the directory.

Comment: You can use the [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) API. You'll have do it a bit differently though.

Answer (score 1):

> Integration of dropbox in android can be done with [DropBox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android).
>
> [Downloading file from dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134740/cannot-download-file-from-dropbox)

---

> Uploading file to dropbox

---

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Dropbox, Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */




import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.UploadRequest;
import com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxFileSizeException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxIOException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxParseException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxPartialFileException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxServerException;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/**
 * Here we show uploading a file in a background thread, trying to show
 * typical exception handling and flow of control for an app that uploads a
 * file from Dropbox.
 */
public class Upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;
    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private String mErrorMsg;


    public Upload(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
                  File file) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                try {
                    mRequest.abort();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                    new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public long progressInterval() {
                            // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                            return 500;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                            publishProgress(bytes);
                        }
                    });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int) (100.0 * (double) progress[0] / mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
}
```

> Call the method

```
Upload upload = new Upload(context, mApi, mPath, file);
upload.execute();
```

> Where, mApi is the reference of DropboxAPI

Comment: is there no generalized intent-like method yet? I thought for sure google would go that route so they could pre-include saving to google drive in their api